# Getting my first view that use Mvc.JQuery.Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, datatables

I am working on an asp.net mvc web application, and i want to use the strongly typed version of jQuery-Datatables plugin as mentioned on this link [Link](http://mvcjquerydatatables.apphb.com/).

so i created a new asp.net mvc-5 web application, then i added the `Mvc.Jquery.Datatables` using the "Manage Nuget Package" dialog , as follow:-

[image]

[image]

Then i Accept the license and after that the following was added to my project:-

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages;
using Mvc.JQuery.Datatables;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(WebApplication27.RegisterDatatablesModelBinder), "Start")]

namespace WebApplication27 {
    public static class RegisterDatatablesModelBinder {
        public static void Start() {
            if (!ModelBinders.Binders.ContainsKey(typeof(DataTablesParam)))
                ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DataTablesParam), new Mvc.JQuery.Datatables.DataTablesModelBinder());
        }
```

}

but can anyone adivce how i can get the `MVC.jquery.datatable` functionalists inside my view, for example i have the following basic Index action method:-

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var emps = db.Emps.Include(e => e.Dept);
            return View(emps.ToList());
        }
```

and the related view:-

```
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication27.Models.Emp>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Dept.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dept.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EmpID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EmpID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EmpID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

so how i need to modify them to allow MVc.jquery.datatable functionality?

Thanks

Comment: I have used datatables extensively in MVC, but not the versions installed via Nuget. I imagine they're pretty similar.  So you will now populate the table using ajax which means you don't pass the model to the View.  The table should have no row data, just empty `<tbody>` tags.  You need some js datatable initialisation code which populates the table from an MVC method.  Probably best to have a look at a server-side example or tutorial.

Comment: @markpsmith but i want to use the strongly types version of the datatables, so that i can benefit from the model binder ,, can you adivce on this please? second question, from where i can find tutorials on this (strongly typed datatables ?)..

Comment: Have you seen the [examples?](http://aspdatatables.azurewebsites.net/)

Comment: i already read these examples, and they do not explain how to get things working,, i found it difficult to understand when i should use @Html.Partial and what is the purpose of  Html.DataTableVm , and many things ... i am searching for some documentations and not just tutorials and code... can you adivce ?

Comment: I think the question you're asking too broad, which is why you're not getting any answers. If you're stuck on specifics, then ask questions about them.  Looking at the examples: `@Html.Partial` is the code that renders a partial View. `Html.DataTableVm` is an extension method that renders the datatable

Comment: my question is that i am trying to understand how to get the dataTable works inside ym asp.net mvc web application. and to be able to do so i need to find relative documentations and not just tutorials and examples which do not provide any explanation,,,

Comment: 'get the dataTable works inside my asp.net mvc web application' - by installing the Nuget package _you have already done this_